# How to block all aplications from internet connection?

Tags: firewalls, windows-10

I would like to block all windows10 applications from internet access
So I found a settings screen on the windows firewall (Windows Firewall\Allowed apps) I would like to uncheck everything from this list..

My question is what is the absolute must for windows itself (like core network) 
to have internet access so it must stay checked on this list?

[image: Allowed apps]

Comment: You can run Windows on a system which isn't connected to any network, if you want, so presumably none of them are absolutely essential. Probably easier to not connect it to a network in that case though. This sounds like an X-Y problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to achieve?